# Formatting a Search Result using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin, echo

I'm tweaking the administrator side to the site at the moment, where a site administrator is allowed to enter the flight number, and the database will pull down the names of all the people on the flight. However, at the moment my results are looking a bit like this:

`The following people are on this flight Joe BloggsThe following people are on this flight Gareth RobertsThe following people are on this flight Joe BloggsThe following people are on this flight Gareth RobertsThe following people are on this flight Joe BloggsThe following people are on this flight Gareth RobertsThe following people are on this flight Joe BloggsThe following people are on this flight Gareth RobertsThe following people are on this flight Joe BloggsThe following people are on this flight Gareth RobertsThe following people are on this flight Joe Bloggs`

You get the idea...names obviously made up for DPA reasons :)

How can I get it to say for example:

Passenger's on flight number 2021 are:

- Name one
- Name two
- Name three

Here's my code, and I welcome any advice at all!

```
    <? 
     include("logon/include/session.php");
                $loggedinuser = $session->username;
    $passengerNo = $_POST['enteredPassNo'];
       $theflightno = $_POST['enteredflightNo'];
            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT p.surname, p.forename,   p.passNo FROM PASSENGER p WHERE p.passNo = '$passengerNo'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
    echo "Welcome to the site"  . " " . $row['forename'] ." ";
        }
        echo mysql_error();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT    p.surname, p.forename, p.passNo, p.flightNo FROM PASSENGER p, FLIGHT_INFO f WHERE     p.flightNo = '$theflightno'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
    echo "The following people are on this flight" . "</ br> ";
    echo $row['forename'] ." " . $row['surname'];
    echo "</ br>";
        echo mysql_error();
        }
    echo mysql_error();
       ?>
```

It's query2 that is more the focus, query1 is being used for a few tests really!
And just to clarify, the values stored in $passengerNo and $theflightNo are being correctly assigned after being posted from the form.

Many thanks,

Tom

**EDIT: Great advice on the formatting, but it's still printing as such:-**

The following people are on this flight

- Gareth Roberts
- Joe Bloggs
- Gareth Roberts
- Joe Bloggs
- Gareth Roberts
- Joe Bloggs

Rather than printing,

The following people are on this flight:-

- Gareth Roberts
- Joe Bloggs

Just once etc :)

Comment: Ok, regarding the recent edit in your query, I have edited my reply. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249004/1190388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the segment after `$query2` to this:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(p.surname, p.forename) as name, p.passNo, 
         p.flightNo FROM PASSENGER p WHERE p.flightNo = '$theflightno' 
         GROUP BY name");
echo "Passengers on flight number {$theflightno} are:" . "<br /> <ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
  echo "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
  echo "</ br>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

### *EDIT*

The basic edit I did was:

- Added a [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, so that names will be returned as a single string(for repeated values of surnames/fornames).
- Changing the query, to  include a `GROUP BY` clause. So that repeated names(forname+surname) will appear only once.

Comment: This is fantastic, many thanks for your help. Exactly what I am after!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "The following people are on flight " . $row['flightNo'] . "</ br> ";    
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))

{

echo "<li>" . $row['forename'] ." " . $row['surname'] . "</li>";

    }
 echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Hi all, great formatting, but explained the problem further in edit to original post!

Comment: @TomGillespie as per your question, this is what you actually require. Also, [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59757)

Comment: @Chasing Death he is saying that it's looping the rows more than it should, focusing on the return values, not the formatting

Comment: Didn't know that, many thanks, I shall remember this in future!

Comment: @techjunkie.css That's right, the formatting I have been able to solve, and updated original post in order to reflect niggly issue in regards to looping more rows than it should. Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

you are looping the text too. So

```
echo "Passenger's on flight number 2021 are:";
echo '</ br>';
echo '<ul>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
  echo '<li>';
  echo $row['forename'] ." " . $row['surname'];
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```